# Finding if string is concatenation of others

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, permutation

I am working on a problem where one must determine if a string is a concatenation of other string (these strings can be repeated in the concatenated strings). I am using backtracking to be as efficient as possible. If the string is a concatenation, it will print the strings it is a concatenation of. If not, it will print `NOT POSSIBLE`. Here is my python code:

```
# note: strList has to have been sorted
def findFirstSubstr(strList, substr, start = 0):
    index = start
    if (index >= len(strList)):
        return -1
    while (strList[index][:len(substr)] != substr):
        index += 1
        if (index >= len(strList)):
            return -1
    return index


def findPossibilities(stringConcat, stringList):
    stringList.sort()
    i = 0
    index = 0
    substr = ''
    resultDeque = []
    indexStack = []
    while (i < len(stringConcat)):
        substr += stringConcat[i]
        index = findFirstSubstr(stringList, substr, index)
        if (index < 0):
            if (len(resultDeque) == 0):
                return 'NOT POSSIBLE'
            else:
                i -= len(resultDeque.pop())
                index = indexStack.pop() + 1
                substr = ''
                continue
        elif (stringList[index] == substr):
            resultDeque.append(stringList[index])
            indexStack.append(index)
            index = 0
            substr = ''
        i += 1
    return ' '.join(resultDeque)
```

I keep failing the last half of the test cases and can't figure out why. Could someone prompt me in the right direction for any cases that this would fail? Thanks!

Comment: FYI: if you want a deque, use the `deque` class in [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Comment: @ChristianDean thanks for the advice. I'm new to Python and am just using the list because that's all I know

Comment: Yeah, I thought I might mention it since you said you were looking for speed. Because its a dedicated deque it will be a faster than a standard Python list(assmuing of course, you _use_ it like a deque).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, of all, this code is unnecessary complicated. For example, here is an equivalent but shorter solution:

```
def findPossibilities(stringConcat, stringList):
    if not stringConcat:  # if you want exact match, add `and not stringList`
        return True

    return any(findPossibilities(stringConcat[len(s):],
                                 stringList[:i] + stringList[i+1:])  # assuming non-repeatable match. Otherwise, simply replace with `stringList`
               for i, s in enumerate(stringList)
               if stringConcat.startswith(s))
```

Actual answer:

Border condition: remaining part of `stringConcat` matches some of `stringList`, search is stopped:

```
>>> findPossibilities('aaaccbbbccc', ['aaa', 'bb', 'ccb', 'cccc'])
'aaa ccb bb'
```

Comment: It'll take me a bit to sort through your code but upvoting for the border condition